# Android - How come user has to hold one finger down while using the other finger to swipe up and down to scroll successfully?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Currently I have the below code for a layout (which is used for a class that extends Fragment):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/_image" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The ImageView contains an image that is longer than the device's height, therefore requires scrolling up and down to view all of it.

I am able to scroll up and down on the image only if I hold one finger down while using the other finger to swipe up and down (note, I am not able to scroll up and down on the image if I only using one finger to swipe up and down).

Was wondering if anyone knows how to solve this? (i.e. to make it so that I am able to scroll up and down on the image by using one finger only) (thanks in advance)